# Using setInterval in JavaScript without using an inline, anonymous function

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to achieve is that initially data will be loaded and then be updated every ten minutes using the same function.

Consider this code:

```
var updateNamespace = (function() {
    var object = '#updates',
    load = 'loader';

    return {
        update: function() {
            $(object).addClass(load).load('update.php', function(reponse, status, xhr) {
                if (status == 'error') {
                    $(this).html('<li>Sorry but there was an error in loading the news &amp; updates.</li>');
                }
                $(this).removeClass(load);
            }); 
        }
    }
})();

setInterval(updateNamespace.update(), 600000);
```

I get this error:

```
useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)
```

How can I fix this?

What's a better and more elegant way of writing this or using the `setInterval` function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use:

```
setInterval(updateNamespace.update, 600000);
```

(Note the removed invocation() operator.)

Your code, as written, will actually invoke `updateNamespace.update` when you call setInterval.  Hence,

```
setInterval(updateNamespace.update(), 600000);
```

evaluates to

```
setInterval(undefined, 600000);
```

You want to pass `setInterval` a REFERENCE to your function, not the result of its invocation.

Comment: Nice answer! In my case, I had to send parameters to the function called by setInterval.  Then, I put them on a greater scope (not global thought).  It works as a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason JavaScript wants to see quotes around the method your calling. As if it was a string. Not sure why it works like that. Matt H. said if you pass a reference that will fix the problem. But it won't work if you need to pass in an argument. So I don't know maybe JavaScript just saves the method as a string and then coverts to back to normal when it's used.

Answer (score -5):

try `setInterval('updateNamespace.update()', 600000);`

Note the quotes around the function call